# Navigate to different screens using same back button depending on which view controller it came from

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to check which view controller the page was displayed from and change the action on the back button depending on that which view controller it came from. How would I write an if statement to find out the previous view controller? I've tried this code below but it did not work.

```
// MARK: - IBActions
@IBAction func backBarBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    Notify.post(sender: self, type: .closeConnectiongScreenStack)
    //UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(VCManager.get(.customSideMenuVC), animated: true, completion: nil)
    if topVC() == VCManager.get(.deviceSyncedVC){
        let controller = VCManager.get(.customSideMenuVC) as! UINavigationController
        presentVC(controller)
    }else {
        dismissVC(completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform some action _in addition to_ navigating back to the previous VC? If not, you don’t need a custom action at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a navigation controller you could check your presenting view controller instance with `is`:

```
let presentingVC = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController

if presentingVC is YourViewController { // <-- Change YourViewController with your view controller name
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use navigation controller delegate with `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` function(
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621878-navigationcontroller)

and then use `navigationController.topViewController` in order to get the top view controller on the stack before it is being dismissed. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621849-topviewcontroller)

not sure if it will work, but i think it should